# Why doesn't Oracle properly support 64bit java for unix?

Tags: 64-bit, unix, java

http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp has an insulting note:

> Please use the 32-bit version for
>   Java applet and Java Web Start
>   support.

for both Solaris and for Linux.

Why doesn't Oracle do a proper job and release full 64 bit support for unix? Are there any technical reasons for this lack of support, or is it purely political? Has Oracle stated anything official about when/if this will be fixed? Will OpenJDK 7 eventually support this?

Answer (score 1):

Sun didn't have a 64-bit Java applet for Linux either. [IcedTea](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page) already does.

Comment: The good folks at Oracle™ have informed me that openjdk is piracy and since I already use a dalvik based phone I don't want to further jeopardise their bottom line. Do you have any idea how much a yacht race costs?

Answer (score -1):

Historically, plug-in vendors have not bothered making 64-bit versions of their plug-ins as consumers don’t have 64-bit Web browsers. The browser vendors of course haven’t bothered to make 64-bit versions as there are no plug-ins for them. Which would not go down too well with their users, who would of course blame the browser (the front-end they interact with) vendor not the plug-in vendor.

With Windows Vista and 7 64-bit, Microsoft ship a 64-bit version of Internet Explorer. Hopefully this will be enough to make plug-in vendors hurry with their 64-bit deployment.

*Disclaimer: I am an employee of Opera Software ASA. This posting is my own opinion.*

Comment: The question asks about Linux and Solaris, both of which have had 64-bit browsers for a while now.